# Other users seeing a 3rd party website with same user stylesheet

Tags: css, browser, userstyles

I have a group of users that will be using a web database.

Ideally, I would like these users to view that website with some user styles of our creation (so that some of the website elements are displayed differently, like highlighting fields they need to fill out).  These users are independent and remote, meaning that we can't really access their computers to do anything to set this up (like setting up Stylish for them).

I was wondering if we could somehow create a package that will display the website using such stylesheet, as if it was an application rather than a website that they visit with their browser.

The idea would be that by opening this "app" they're actually opening a dedicated browser window to this webpage where they can interact with it, can't navigate away (just no address bar), **and**  uses this stylesheet I mentioned.  Thus the "as if it was an app".

I hope I was sufficiently clear. I don't even know what this would be called (not even what tags to use), so my research has really taken me nowhere.  Guidance on how to get this done will be highly appreciated.  If somebody has a better idea of how to obtain a similar result, I'll be happy to experiment!!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use any SDK for desktop applications that have web view component and inject your css into html loaded in that web view.

Comment: For example, you can use http://electron.atom.io

Comment: thanks mixel, it looks like that'd be the way to go. I will have to look into it and I'm not sure I have the chops, but good opportunity to develop new skills :)

Answer (score 0):

Will the users be logging in through user accounts in your database?

If so, create a column in the user database which, should it return a certain value (say true for these special users and false for all else) then a different stylesheet is used.

Comment: yes, they will be logging in but I don't know how something like what you suggest would be implemented.

Comment: So if, on your users db, there was a column called special_theme and users had a value true or a value valse. Then, in your document head where you call the theme, you can say if(special_theme==true){ call 1 theme; } else{ call another;}